# How do I remap <c-x><c-k> to work with fzf.vim completion?

Tags: key-bindings, tmux, fzf

I'm trying to set up work completion with fzf.vim. Following the manual, I have:

```
inoremap <expr> <c-x><c-k> fzf#vim#complete#word({'window': { 'width': 0.2, 'height': 0.9, 'xoffset': 1 }})
```

However, this conflicts with a tmux setting I have which maps c-k to move up a pane. To work around it, I tried:

```
imap <expr> <leader>k fzf#vim#complete#word({'window': { 'width': 0.2, 'height': 0.9, 'xoffset': 1 }})
imap <leader>k <c-x><c-k>
```

But this is not triggering the fzf completion.

Comment: Either remove tmux global mapping of `<C-k>` or use another non-conflicting combination in vim.

Answer (score 1):

you can execute command in insert like that `<C-o>:echo "test"<cr>` :

```
inoremap <leader>k <C-o>:fzf#vim#complete#word({'window': { 'width': 0.2, 'height': 0.9, 'xoffset': 1 }})<cr>
```